# Makefile runs default-python

Tags: python, macos, makefile, psycopg2

I'm running the command

```
make config=default_config.mk task
```

with task being different tasks I can run. The entire program is pretty dated with very little support. The 'default_config.mk' file lets you change directorys, after that the programm is supposed to work.

It turns out the makefile runs the default-python. The Makefile basically runs a bunch of different .py-files.

I've already created an alias for python3 which works in the terminal, but not when I run the program. I've now created a new Makerun-file and changed every python to python3. Apart from that and adding '#!/bin/bash' to the first line (to make it executable?) it should be the same file.
Now, I keep getting the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `task'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you

Edit:

So I've managed to install Psycopg2 to Python 2.7, now it throws an error for the command:

```
python SciGRID.py --dbpwrd $(postgres_password)
```

Error:

```
SciGRID.py: error: --dbpwrd option requires an argument
```

The Programm is supposed to run on Python 2.7. I think the best way would be to change the Makefile, but that's when the error "no rule..." appears. If I use the default Makefile I basically keep running into errors as its pretty dated. Why is it not accepting the edited makefile?

Comment: We don't really have enough information to answer the question.  "No rule to make target `task'" suggests that 'task' is not one of the supported tasks.  Make sure you have not misspelled it (I presume that the question is using the literal "task" as a placeholder for one or more of the program's actual task names).

Comment: Alternatively, the command-line argument `config=default_config.mk` suggests that the makefile will attempt to `include` the contents of file `default_config.mk`.  In that case, even if you have not modified the main makefile, you may have introduced an error into it by modifying `default_config.mk`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried adding more info, the "no rule..." error only appears with the edited makefile. The 'config=default_config.mk' does indeed gets included from the makefile, but you are supposed to edit that file and there is no problem with that as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't edit `default_config.mk`, though in fact, it would probably be a better idea to make a copy of it in another file, edit *that*, and provide that file's name.  But the original point was that you may have introduced an error into the makefile through your edits to `default_config.mk`.

Comment: Your new error message seems to indicate that variable `postgres_password` does not have a value assigned.

Comment: We really cannot give you very much in the way of specific advice with the limited information provided.  Our usual standard is a [mre], and the question contains nothing remotely like that.